# Removing empty strings or undefined properties from a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object like this:

```
filters = { loaderId:1111, search : '', postCategory: '', sortBy:'' }
```

I'd like to remove blank properties (empty string, undefined, null) but keep properties that are 0.

How can I do this with javascript, I'd have done this with lodash omit but now it's deprecated, thanks in advance!

Comment: When was `omit` deprecated? [I can't see it in the list of deprecated methods](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Deprecations) nor does it say anything in [the documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit).

Comment: It was in 5.0 I think

Comment: OK, I found it [on the roadmap](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Roadmap). It's indeed being removed. Weirdly, in favour of `pick`. The two work fundamentally differently, so I'm not sure removing `omit` is a good idea. Unless the functionality is somehow folded into `pick` but this is odd.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
function clean(obj) {
  for (let propName in obj) { 
    if (obj[propName] === null || obj[propName] === undefined || obj[propName] === '') {
      delete obj[propName];
    }
  }
}
```

or, something like

```
const removeEmpty = obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => (obj[key] == null || obj[key] == undefined || obj[key] === '') && delete obj[key]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function:

```
function clearEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
        if(obj[key] !== null && obj[key] !== undefined && obj[key] !== '') {
            acc[key] = obj[key];
        }

        return acc;
    }, {});
}
```

I'll return a new object instead of mutating the original, in case you might need to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var filters = {
  loaderId: 1111,
  search: 0,
  postCategory: "",
  sortBy: ""
};

for (var prop in filters) {
  if (!filters[prop] && filters[prop] !== 0)
    delete filters[prop];
}
console.log(filters)
```

Answer (score 0):

[omitBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omitBy) is not on the [roadmap](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Roadmap) to be deprecated. If you already have lodash in your project you could simply do:

```
_.omitBy(obj, v => v !== 0 && !v);
```

Answer (score 0):

One-line solution:

```
 Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(input).filter(x => x[1] !==''));
```

---

Since

```
Object.entries = 
[
  [ 'loaderId', 1111 ],
  [ 'search', '' ],
  [ 'postCategory', '' ],
  [ 'sortBy', '' ]
]
```

And below returns [ 'loaderId', 1111 ]

```
Object.entries(input).filter(x => x[1] !=='')
```

And below convert it to an object:

```
{ 'loaderId' : 1111 }
```